# Error after requesting to install an app on device from store

Tags: wso2, wso2-appm, wso2-iot

I get the following error after a few seconds, or even minutes, when trying to install an app from the store (AppManager).

[image: Error message]

The wso2carbon.log file doesn't show any error message.

I'm using the WSO2 EMM version 3.3.0 and the device is an Android 8.
It does enroll correctly, and even receives device operations such as: send ring device, and send message.

I looked for enabling debug message log, but I didn't find it for the version of wso2 iot server that I am testing.

Where can I find some clues to solve this issue?

How can I enable debug message logging for the AppManager?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not on the EMM server but rather on the EMM Android Agent. The server just receives an "ERROR" status from the EMM agent upon failure.

I recommend you run the EMM agent in debug on the device to see what is causing the issue.

I have run into many "INSTALL_APPLICATION" errors, it could be any or none of these:

- Download location differs on the device
- Network issues during download
- Volley issues (HTTP library) - was mostly version issues
- Server not allowing HTTP calls (only HTTPS) which is the default for installing apps
- Device Owner/Device Admin not set correctly
- Missing permissions

What you can see on the HTTP access logs is whether the install is occurring but looking to see whether the APK is downloading, log entry will look like this:

```
[21/Jun/2019:14:48:19 +0200] "GET /store/api/mobileapp/getfile/6THVwGRMTAG5wD7.apk HTTP/1.1" 200 3803551 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ), Android"
```

If you see the APK being downloaded then you know for sure the issue is NOT on the server.